# nosetests - excluding a dir from the coverage report

Tags: python, nose, coverage.py, python-coverage

I have my python app structured as follows:

```
proj
   - comp1
   - comp2
tests
   - comp1
   - comp2
other
   - contains some python code
```

I am running nosetests as following:

```
nosetests --with-coverage  --cover-package=proj --exclude-dir=other -v tests
```

However, in the coverage report that nosetests prints at the end I still entries from 'other'.  How do I exclude 'other' from the coverage report?

Answer (score 0):

Quite possible your `tests` or `proj` are referring to the `other` python code, and as result, it makes it into report. You could see debug coverage plugin printout with:

```
nosetests --with-coverage  --cover-package=proj -vv tests -l nose.plugins.cover
```

Comment: Yes, proj refers to the 'other' python code. The 'other' is in fact a set of third party python libraries.  And that's why I would like to exclude it from the coverage report.